# R Shiny — check file size before uploading?

Tags: r, memory, shiny, upload

I want to prevent users from uploading files that exceed my server's memory. Is there a way to check the file size **before** the upload?

Something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Big file")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$file, {
      if(size > max_size) { # how do I do this part?
          showNotification("File is too big", type = "error")
      }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Since the mentioned answers only work, if a file could be uploaded. If the file size is too big, there is nothing to observe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes on the first line of your `server` function add a line like this: `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)` for example this would limit the upload file size to 30MB.

so it should look like:

```
...
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
...
```

Comment: I want to give users a custom notification when they upload a large file. Is there a way to trigger a reactive function when `maxRequestSize` is exceeded?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the function `file.info("filename")$size` might be helpful to you, this will return the size of a given file, then compare that to the `shiny.maxRequestSize`